# iLO Windows Server 2016 automated deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, windows-server-2016, ilo

For a new build-out I have to install Windows Server 2016 on several bare metal HP Gen9 hosts.

I won't have SSCM or any other tools available and am pretty much limited to iLO and Powershell.

From my research it appears it is possible to automate the deployment via Powershell but I have not found a comprehensive guide to walk me through this.

Does anyone have guidance on a) creating a fully patched Windows Server 2016 image suitable for automated/unattended deployment and b) the process on automating the deployment of that image to various hosts via powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/mdt/) (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit). Even if you had SCCM, it still uses MDT for OS deployments.